# Правка запроса My SQL

Tags: mysql

```
   select       ((now(),'%s') - (users.data,'%s'))/(60 * 60 * 24) || ' д ' ||
                                (((now(),'%s') - (users.data,'%s')) % (60 * 60 * 24))/(60 * 60)  || ' ч ' ||
                                  ((((now(),'%s') - (users.data,'%s')) % (60 * 60 * 24)) % (60 * 60))/60  || ' м ' 
                                  from users where userId= 999929921;
```

переделываю склайт на mysql ,не могу никак добить этот запрос
нужно чтобы от текущего времени отнималось время записанное в таблице и выводилось в формате 00д00ч00м
база ругается 
operand should contain 1 column

Comment: зачем конкретно у Вас используется в запросе `||` - оператор "или"? и что именно Вы хотели сделать вот этим: `(now(),'%s') - (users.data,'%s')`

Comment: переведите все времена в unix_timestamp и спокойно вычитайте, потом приводите обратно к datetime

Comment: и как это реализовать в одном запросе Mike?в таблице мне нужны даты в обычном формате,получается нужно перевести ,вычесть разнцицу и потом каким то образом привести это к формату дни-часы-минуты.помоему это нереализуемо в одном запросе

Comment: александр вы видете код запроса?видете что он должен выводить?Нужно высчитать разницу между двумя датами с часами и минутами и вывести это пользователю в формате дни -часы -минуты.ВОт этим (now(),'%s') - (users.data,'%s') вычисляется разница в секундах межу текущем временем и заданой датой из таблицы.По крайне мере так это работало в склайте.

Comment: сам спросил сам ответил,кому нужно вот решение    SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now())-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(users.data)) from users where UserId=999929921;